# incementing in double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, double-pointer

```
    int main()
    {
static int x[]={100,200,300,400,500};
static int *p={x+2,x,x+3,x+4,x+1};
int **ptr=p;
ptr++;
printf("%d",*ptr);

return 0;
```

}

can anyone please explain why is the output 500, initially ptr contains x+2, after incrementation, it should contain x and the output should be 100, but the output is 500. I don't know why!
A lot of guys are concerned about the warning and norms of C , the thing is this is a textbook question and i need to find the output ,and how i got the output
Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Are you not getting a warning for `int **ptr=p;`? Or `printf("%d",*ptr);`?

Comment: Do you have a [compilable version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4e71fb444517b9e) of this code also?

Comment: `ptr` is a pointer to a pointer. `*ptr` is a pointer. You print that pointer, not what `*ptr` is pointing to (which would be `**ptr`). A decent compiler should warn you about mismatching `printf` formatting and argument.

Comment: I am new to c programming, and i need to find the output of this code and how i got this , any help is appreciated??

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: @Galik it does , try gdb online C complier

Comment: Sorry, you tagged this as `C++`, I didn't realize it's `C`.

Comment: Actually, you don't allocate memory for p array here. You should have had to write it as int p[] = {x+2,x+3,x+4,x+1};

Comment: No, your code doesn't compile with GDB online compiler. It gives several errors. Concentrate on the first error which is `main.c:14:30: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer                                                                  
     static int* p = { x + 2, x, x + 3, x + 4, x + 1 }; `

Comment: This line is wrong: `static int *p={x+2,x,x+3,x+4,x+1};`, even if your compiler happens to accept it. It looks like it should be an array.

Comment: what did you tried to do? you are playing with the pointers but it is not clear what you want to do here..

Comment: @AsafItach, this was my homework and i need to find the output.

Comment: > the thing is this is a textbook question and i need to find the output ,and how i got the output Any help is appreciated!! I suspect your textbook suggest you to find errors here.

Comment: @bimjhi i think you are right there should be int *p[];

Answer (score 0):

if you change this

```
int main() {
  static int x[]={100,200,300,400,500};
  static int *p={x+2,x,x+3,x+4,x+1};
  int **ptr=p;
  ptr++;
  printf("%d",*ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

to this

```
int main() {
  static int x[]={100,200,300,400,500};
  static int *p[]={x+2,x,x+3,x+4,x+1};
  int **ptr=p;
  ptr++;
  printf("%d",**ptr);

  return 0;
}
```

the output will be: 100

change `printf("%d",*ptr);` to this `printf("%d",**ptr);`

and this `static int *p={x+2,x,x+3,x+4,x+1};` to this 
`static int *p[]={x+2,x,x+3,x+4,x+1};`

Consider compiling your C code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked with all warnings and debug info: 
 `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then using the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger

Comment: @Sagarb is this answering your question?